# Error 500 on firebug report when add record with ajax on Yii Framework

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, yii

I try using ajax on yii framework. When I try to add record to database, it comes unsuccessful. The button always freeze at the loading state. Displaying record is fine, data was showing up, but it didn't work when try add new record or edit the record. For delete record, it's working.

Here is `AjaxController.php`:

```
<?php
class AjaxController extends Controller {

    public $layout = "null";

    public function actionIndex() {
        $this -> render('index');
    }

    public function actionCreate() {            
        if (Yii::app() -> request -> isAjaxRequest) {
            $modelProduk = new Produk;
            if ($_POST) {
                $modelProduk['nama_produk'] = $_POST['namaproduk'];
                $modelProduk['jumlah_produk'] = $_POST['jumlahproduk'];
                $modelProduk['harga_produk'] = $_POST['hargaproduk'];
                $modelProduk -> save();
            }
            $this -> render('create');
        }
    }

    public function actionIndexproduk() {

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria( array('order' => 'id_produk DESC'));
        $count = Produk::model() -> count($criteria);
        $pages = new CPagination($count);
        $pages -> pageSize = 2;
        $pages -> applyLimit($criteria);
        $dataProduk = Produk::model() -> findAll($criteria);
        $this -> render('indexproduk', array('dataProduk' => $dataProduk, 'pages' => $pages, ));
    }

    public function actionUpdate($id) {
        if (Yii::app() -> request -> isAjaxRequest) {
            $dataProduk = Produk::model() -> findByPk($id);
            if ($_POST) {
                $dataProduk -> nama_produk = $_POST['namaproduk'];
                $dataProduk -> jumlah_produk = $_POST['jumlahproduk'];
                $dataProduk -> harga_produk = $_POST['hargaproduk'];
                $dataProduk -> save();
            }
            $this -> render('update', array('dataProduk' => $dataProduk));
        }
    }

    public function actionDelete($id) {
        if (Yii::app() -> request -> isAjaxRequest) { 
            Produk::model() -> deleteByPk($id);
        }
    }

    public function actionSearch($criteria = '') {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria( array(
            'select' => '*',
            'condition' => "nama_produk LIKE '%$criteria%'",
            'order' => 'id_produk DESC', ));

        $count = Produk::model() -> count($criteria);
        $pages = new CPagination($count);
        $pages -> pageSize = 2;
        $pages -> applyLimit($criteria);
        $model = Produk::model() -> findAll($criteria);
        $this -> render('indexProduk', array('dataProduk' => $model, 'pages' => $pages));
    }
}
?>
```

This is `index.php` under views/ajax dir:

```
<div id="form"></div>
<div id="data"></div>
<?php 
   Yii::app() -> clientScript -> registerCoreScript('jquery',   
   CClientScript::POS_BEGIN);
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").load('<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/ajax/create');
    $('#data').load('<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/ajax/indexproduk');
});
</script>
```

This is code line from `indexproduk.php` :

```
<form action="" method="post" id="formSearch">
    <input type="text" name="criteria" id="criteria" />
    <input type="button" value="Search" id="buttonSearch" />
</form>

<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>         
        <th>Nama Produk</th>
        <th>Jumlah Produk</th>
        <th>Harga Produk</th>
        <th>#</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($dataProduk as $produk){?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $produk -> nama_produk;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $produk -> jumlah_produk;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $produk -> harga_produk;?></td>
        <td>
        <a href="#" class="update" id="<?php echo $produk->id_produk;?>">Edit</a> ||
        <a href="#" class="delete" id="<?php echo $produk->id_produk;?>">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>
<br>
<?php     
    $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
        'header'=>'',       
        'maxButtonCount'=>5,
        'pages' => $pages,       
    )) 
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //search
        $("#buttonSearch").click(function(){
        var criteria = $('#criteria').val();
        $("#data").load('<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/ajax/search/criteria/'+criteria);
        });

        $('li a').click(function(){
            /*ambil value dari attribut href 
            dan load ke <div id=”data” */
            $('#data').load($(this).attr('href'));
            return false;
        });

        $('.update').click(function(){              
            var id =$(this).attr('id'); 
             $('#form').load('<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/ajax/update/'+id);
            return false;
        });         

        $('.delete').click(function(){
        var id =$(this).attr('id'); 
        $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
             url:'<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/ajax/delete/'+id,
             success:function(data){
              $('#data').load('<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/ajax/indexproduk');
             }
          });
          return false;
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Last file,  `create.php`:

```
<h3>Create Data Produk</h3>
<form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nama Produk</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="namaproduk" size="50" />  
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jumlah Produk</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="jumlahproduk" size="5" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Harga Produk</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="hargaproduk" size="25" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input id="create" type="button" value="Create" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#create').click(function(){          
        $('#create').attr({
            value : 'loading..',
            disabled : true,
        });         
        var myFormData = $("#myForm").serialize();          
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url : '<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/ajax/create',
            data:myFormData,
            success:function(data){
                $('#data').load('<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/ajax/indexproduk');
                $('#create').attr({
                    value : 'Create',
                    disabled : false,
                });
                $('#myForm')[0].reset();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Model `Produk.php`:

```
<?php
class Produk extends CActiveRecord {

    public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName() {
        return 'produk';
    }

    public function rules() {
        return array( 
            array('nama_produk ,jumlah_produk, harga_produk', 'required',),
            array('jumlah_produk,harga_produk','numerical','integerOnly'=>true,),
        );
    }

    public function attributeLabels() {
        return array(
            'nama_produk' => 'Nama Produk', 
            'jumlah_produk'=>'Jumlah Produk',
            'harga_produk'=>'Harga Produk',
        );
    }

}
?>
```

FYI : I'm using XAMPP 1.8.3 with PHP version 5.5.15 on Windows 8 with Mozilla Firefox 32.0.1.

Looking forward to see an experts suggestion here.

Edit : Here firebug Report

```
Here what i got from firebug :

<h1>PHP Error [2]</h1>
<p>include(jumlah_produk.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\YiiBase.php:427)</p>
<pre>#0 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(427): CWebApplication->handleError()
#1 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(427): autoload()
#2 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\YiiBase.php(302): autoload()
#3 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\validators\CValidator.php(186): import()
#4 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\base\CModel.php(287): createValidator()
#5 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\base\CModel.php(260): Produk->createValidators()
#6 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\base\CModel.php(158): Produk->getValidators()
#7 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(805): Produk->validate()
#8 I:\xampp\htdocs\yiites\protected\controllers\AjaxController.php(18): Produk->save()
#9 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(49): AjaxController->actionCreate()
#10 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams()
#11 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CController.php(286): AjaxController->runAction()
#12 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CController.php(265): AjaxController->runActionWithFilters()
#13 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): AjaxController->run()
#14 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController()
#15 I:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#16 I:\xampp\htdocs\yiites\index.php(12): CWebApplication->run()
</pre>
```

Comment: So you've got a server side error, what did the server logs say when you looked?

Comment: I Edited the Question, adding model code & report from firebug.

Comment: Yii is looking for a file named `jumlah_produk.php` which is not there. In your create action the three lines about `$modelProduk['nama_produk']` should be `$modelProduk->nama_produk` as this is an attribute of the model. Don't know if this is the error though.

Comment: @chris---Hi chris, i resolved it now. Actually there is typo on my model before, which function rules i made as absolute array, i surround all array value with ''. That was causing ajax halted. Now its working fine. $modelProduk->nama_produk is not an error and for a file named jumlah_produk.php it was auto generated from Yii core. If you open the YiiBase.php on line 247 you will se nclude($className.'.php'); 
Btw, thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your model is not valid.
You should always validate your model before saving or handle the return of the sav e function like

```
if($model->save())
 // all good
}
else
{
// something bad happened :(
}
```

What's the error output on the 500? Turn on debug mode in the index.php and maybe add a error_reporting(E_ALL) at the top and enable startup_errors in the php.ini for debug purposes!

another bad idea is reregistering jquery in ajax reply's that kills the dom for the main page so be very careful with that one!

Also ->render renders the whole html page. You may want to just render the partial on an ajax result and return that one to replace the existing page content.

Comment: I add the model now, forget to add it before.